# RaphaëlJS, dojo.gfx, JSXgraph comparison

Tags: svg, raphael, vector-graphics, jsxgraph, dojox.gfx

I'm going to build a simple math graph for a browser application. Therefore all the JS-Vector Libraries might work out well. But I want to know about any experiences you collected using those. For me a basic feature is binding events to paths and points as well as animating paths.

Additionally I am thinking how they are mastering the future. I can imagine to export my drawings as an image or import SVG graphics. Did anyone already experience such cases? What about running them on mobile hardware like iPhone?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I only took the briefest of glances at the competition. Eventually you have to pick one.

I chose RaphaelJS and I have to say it has been an absolute pleasure to use, and the help is fantastic too.

Raphael can do everything you ask for and (like jQuery) you can easily extend it with your own (or others) plugins.

Comment: Just useful information in the anwer

Answer (score 2):

I'm using JSXgraph. It is a greate framework. You can do a lot of stuff with it, also if you don't want a standerd solution. The framework has a well defined API and a lot of examples.

There is a Event system for the elements. I used it and it works greate. Animating pathes shouldn't be a problem. There are lots of demos, also with animated graphes.

> "Additionally I am thinking how they are mastering the future. I can imagine to export my drawings as an image or import SVG graphics."

I've seen a export as static svg, but i do not (re-)find it in the documentation at the moment. I will also need this later in the project. I do not understand, what you mean with import. Do you mean to show Images in the Chart? Then yes you can use images in the drawing Area.

> "Did anyone already experience such cases? What about running them on mobile hardware like iPhone?"

I didn't look for it.